# Making ruby calculator run continuously

Tags: arrays, ruby, while-loop, calculator

I have made a simple calculator in ruby. However after running once the program stops and has to be re-run. I tried the following but it ended in an infinite loop. How can I write this so that it will run until the users tells it to quit?

```
puts "Please enter two digits separated by operation you would like to calculate:"

input = gets.chomp.split(' ')

while input != nil
  if input[1] == "+"
    puts input[0].to_i + input[2].to_i
  elsif input[1] == "-"
    puts input[0].to_i - input[2].to_i
  elsif input[1] == "*"
    puts input[0].to_i * input[2].to_i
  else 
    puts input[0].to_i / input[2].to_i
end
end
```

Comment: `input` will never be `nil`, it's always an Array. Note that in Ruby `x != nil` is really far too much mess, and 99% of the time `while x` will do. The only things logically false are `false` and `nil`. Empty array, empty string, 0, etc. they're all truthful.

Answer (score 0):

`split(' ')` returns an array and not nil, so `input != nil` always evaluates to true, which makes an infinite loop.

You may want to try `while input.size == 2`, or `break` the while loop at certain input like:

```
while true
  # ... if / elsif for operators
  elsif input[1] == 'exit'
    break # end the 'while' loop
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

A recursive approach:

```
def recurs_calc
  puts "Please enter two digits separated by operation you would like to calculate:"
  input = gets.chomp.split(' ')

  if input[1] == "+"
    puts input[0].to_i + input[2].to_i
    recurs_calc
  elsif input[1] == "-"
    puts input[0].to_i - input[2].to_i
    recurs_calc
  elsif input[1] == "*"
    puts input[0].to_i * input[2].to_i
    recurs_calc
  elsif input[1] == '/'
    puts input[0].to_f / input[2].to_i
    recurs_calc
  elsif input[0] == 'exit'
    exit
  else
    puts 'please enter two numbers with SPACES i.e. 4 + 4 then enter'
    recurs_calc
  end
end

recurs_calc
```

Here we recall `recurs_calc` as per conditions and exit when the user types `'exit'`. Note I've also used `to_f` in the `/` branch to get a more accurate result and included a final branch that takes into account an 'incorrect' input. Try running it.

---

Just another approach using `eval` that you may find helpful although this is probably cheating a bit. Also it's considered bad practice to use `eval` for security reasons. Also a special thanks to [@nicael](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38651799/5101493) for the string substitution:

```
loop do
puts "Enter calculation"
input = gets.chomp
  if input == 'exit'
    exit
  else
    p eval (input.gsub(/(\d+)/, '\1.0'))
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

make changes like below:

```
msg = "Please enter two digits separated by operation you would like to calculate:"

puts msg

while input = gets.chomp.split(' ')
  if input[1] == "+"
    puts input[0].to_i + input[2].to_i
  elsif input[1] == "-"
    puts input[0].to_i - input[2].to_i
  elsif input[1] == "*"
    puts input[0].to_i * input[2].to_i
  else
    puts input[0].to_i / input[2].to_i
  end
  puts msg
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This whole thing is a big mess of Ruby that can be drastically simplified by degrees. The key here is to apply the Ruby way to things and elegant solutions become immediately obvious.

Consider replacing that messy `while` loop with an actual `loop` structure. Also name the elements resulting from the `split` based on their meaning to you:

```
loop do
  puts "Please enter two digits separated by operation you would like to calculate:"

  left, operator, right = gets.chomp.split(' ')

  result = case (operator)
  when '+'
    left.to_i + right.to_i
  when '-'
    left.to_i - right.to_i
  when '*'
    left.to_i * right.to_i
  when '/'
    left.to_i / right.to_i
  end

  puts result
end
```

Now this looks like a lot of repetition, the only thing changing here is the operator. Since Ruby is a highly dynamic language we can actually collapse this some more:

```
loop do
  puts "Please enter two digits separated by operation you would like to calculate:"

  left, operator, right = gets.chomp.split(' ')

  result = case (operator)
  when '+', '-', '*', '/'
    left.to_i.send(operator, right.to_i)
  end

  puts result
end
```

Now there's still some duplication here. What about trying to reduce this further and also allow for more flexibility:

```
loop do
  puts "Please enter digits separated by the operations you would like to calculate:"

  values = gets.chomp.split(' ')

  while (values.length > 2)
    left = values.shift.to_i
    operator = values.shift
    right = values.shift.to_i

    values.unshift(left.send(operator, right))
  end

  puts values[0]
end
```

That means you can have arbitrarily long lists of numbers to add together. It's not much harder to make this tokenize your string into numbers and non-number components, but that's something you can try on your own.