# Is there an easy way to convert numbers to floats within a string?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string `input = "2 + 3"` which I would like to convert to `"2.0 + 3.0"`. I have achieved this with the following two convoluted methods:

```
floats   = input.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_f)
operator = input.scan(/[+,\-,*,\/]/)     
operator.unshift(floats.first.to_s)
        .push(floats.last.to_s).join(' ')
#=> "2.0 + 3.0"
```

or:

```
input.split(/\s+/)
     .map{|i| ['+','-','*','/'].include?(i) ? i : i.to_f }
     .join(' ')
#=> "2.0 + 3.0"
```

**Is there an easier or better way to do this?**

Comment: JFYI, this style of breaking method chains over multiple lines (dot first) is IRB-unfriendly. Meaning that if you paste this code in IRB, you'll get a bunch of errors. It is not unlikely to assume that you will want to paste such snippet to IRB sometimes. Therefore, use the other style ([dot last](http://pastie.org/10922739)).

Comment: @SergioTulentsev thank you for this tip and for the earlier intervention.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume you are talking about converting *integers only*, while all other answers assume the string contains *only integers*. I would go with:

```
'1.0 + 2/4.5 - 15'.gsub(/(?<![\.\d])\d+(?![\.\d])/) { |m| "#{m}.0" }
#⇒ "1.0 + 2.0/4.5 - 15.0"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this also

```
> "2 + 3".scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_f).join(" + ")
=> "2.0 + 3.0"
```

After a advice from @sergio I try to do it as a gsub also inspire the above @mudasobwa answer..

```
> "2 + 3/4.5".gsub(/(?<!\.)\b[0-9]+\b(?!\.)/) {|i| i.to_f}
=> "2.0 + 3.0/4.5"
```

also test

```
> "25 + 13/4.5".gsub(/(?<!\.)\b[0-9]+\b(?!\.)/) {|i| i.to_f}
=> "25.0 + 13.0/4.5"
```

Comment: I Apologise that I wasn't clear in my question (although I had hoped it implicit from my attempts) but the code should work for inputs with varying operators i.e. `"2 - 3"`, `"2 * 3"`, or `"2 / 3"`.

Comment: @sag Then try [my suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38651762/is-there-an-easy-way-to-convert-numbers-to-floats-within-a-string/38651799#38651799), it works for such cases.

Comment: @sagarpandya82 you can use operator on join as an argument `s = "  + " or s= " - " or s = " * "` then `"2 + 3".scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_f).join(s)`

Comment: @nicael thank you, your answer is perfect, I already upvoted it.

Comment: @sag Then it's not preffered to use regex? I'm not against no-regex solution, but looks like this is just the easier job for the regex.

Comment: @nicael I am just pointing out why Rajarshi's answer isn't quite right, that's all.

Comment: @sagarpandya82 why it is not right ? may be you do not know what it does or just start learning

Comment: @RajarshiDas I upvoted your answer so it's not my downvote. Your answer isn't ideal because I have to define an `s` operator separately.

Comment: @sagarpandya82 before judge anyone answer you should know a little on the language start learning ruby ....do not know simple...downvote upvote does not matter ...mater judging

Comment: @RajarshiDas: your code completely destroys the original string and tries to reassemble its new form by manually specifiying a separator. You make an (unbased) assumption that strings will consist only of integers and one type of separator. While sagarpaynda82 should have done a better job at providing sample input, one can clearly see that this is a part of math evaluator code. And one should expect all kinds of valid math syntax in input strings. Multiple operators and parentheses, at least. Your code handles none of these.

Comment: @RajarshiDas: even ignoring my assumption about math evaluator, the original requirement is "replace integers with floats". Your code does something else.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev thank you for this suggestion I am fixing it

Answer (score 1):

The regex replace would help here indeed:

```
floats = input.gsub(/(\d+)/, '\1.0')
```

`(\d+)` captures any number and places it in the first capture group. `\1` returns the first capture group (i.e. that number).

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

```
def floatasize(str)
  str.gsub(/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/) { |s| s.include?('.') ? s : "#{s}.0" }
end
```

**Examples**

```
floatasize '1.0 + 2/4.5 - 15'
  #=> "1.0 + 2.0/4.5 - 15.0" 
floatasize '-1 + 2/-4.5 - 15'
  #=> "-1.0 + 2.0/-4.5 - 15.0"
floatasize 'The expression is -1 + 2/-4.5 - 15.'
  #=> "The expression is -1.0 + 2.0/-4.5 - 15."
```

**Explanation**

The regex reads, "match one or more digits optionally followed by a decimal point and then one or more digits". Note that in the last example, the regex matches `"15"`, not `"15."`.

The block could alternatively be written

```
{ |s| "#{s}.0".to_f.to_s }
```

If `gsub` passes `"15"` to the block (`s #=> "15"`),

```
"#{"15"}.0".to_f.to_s
  #=> "15.0".to_f.to_s
  #=> 15.0.to_s
  #=> "15.0"
```

If `gsub` passes `"4.5"` to the block (`s #=> "4.5"`),

```
"#{"4.5"}.0".to_f.to_s
  #=> "4.5.0".to_f.to_s
  #=> 4.5.to_s
  #=> "4.5"
```

Comment: This is superb as usual especially the explanation thank you. Just a little typo in the explanation: _to the block (`s #=> "15"`)_ should read _...(`s #=> "15.0"`)_

Comment: sagar, I believe `s #=> "15"` is correct. There's no `"15.0"` in the string for the regex to match.

Comment: ah gotcha, my misunderstanding.